# How to add punctuation at the end of each row in a data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, stanford-nlp, text-mining, punctuation

So I am currently using the `coreNLP` package in `R`  to perform a sentiment analysis of comments, which I gathered from YouTube using the `tuber`package. My comments are stored in a data frame, where each row represents a comment. For the sentiment analysis each comment needs to end with punctuation, in order to tell the algorithm which are the individual strings to analyze. Is there a convenient way to add punctuation at the end of every row in a data frame? Just a simple dot at the end.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `paste0`.

Example:

```
states <- c('Texas', 'Texas', 'Arizona', 'California', 'California')
states <- paste0(states, ".")

# "Texas."      "Texas."      "Arizona."    "California." "California."
```

Answer (score 1):

If all the comments are on a one column dataframe then `apply` and `paste0` should do the trick.

```
yourDataWithDot <- data.frame(comments = apply(yourData, 1, function(x) paste0(as.character(x), '.')))
```

Answer (score 1):

To build on Yusuf Syakur's answer, if you want to apply the pasting to all of the cells in your data frame instead of individuals columns/vectors, you can simply do this:

```
library(dplyr)

your.df %>% mutate_all(funs(paste(.,".", sep ="")))
```

Comment: What if youtube comment ends with dot? Your solution generates multiple dots...... Also, why do you need `dplyr` when function that actually does all the job is `base::paste`?

Comment: That's right, though the other solutions generate multiple dots as well. For me, `dplyr` is simply more intuitive than `base R` and I see no reason why `base R` should always be preferred

Comment: Thank so very much! multiple dots is not an issue because i already cleaned the dat before, so there will be no dots before using your nice method to place dots at the end :)  thank you